# ExcelLink stop working after Windows 10 update

Tags: interoperability, windows, excel, excellink

After Windows Update KB4508433 & KB4512508, ExcelLink stop to work.
If I uninstall these updates, it work again, but windows return to install them...

```
>> Needs["ExcelLink`"]
>> ExcelInstall[Visible -> True];

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",111,4]. >>

LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",111,4] in LinkClose[LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",111,4]] has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>

>> ExcelRead["A:B"]

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",124,4]. >>

LinkObject::linkn: Argument LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",124,4] in LinkClose[LinkObject["C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\ExcelLink\Binaries\ExcelLink.exe",124,4]] has an invalid LinkObject number; the link may be closed. >>

$Failed
```

Comment: You should probably install KB4512941 (which is listed as an optional update) as well.  Since that fixes a number of issues caused in KB4512508.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ihojnicki said, if you have this problem, just update your system to the last version as it's corrected at this time. By my experience, exact KB***** may differ between different version levels *(I've seen this in W10 1803 & 1903)*.